# Store the result of an async function into a variable

Tags: react-native

I am trying to store the result of an async function into a variable,but the output of my code didn't seems to be the expected one. What am I doing wrong ?

```
async function get_happy_songs() {


let urlOfS = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/happy_songs'
  try {
    let response = await fetch(
      urlOfS, {
        method: 'GET'
      }
    );
    let json = await response.json();
    //console.log(json.melodies);
    return json.melodies;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

//var happy_songs = [];
let happy_songs = get_happy_songs();
console.log(happy_songs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
async function get_happy_songs() {

let urlOfS = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/happy_songs'

return fetch(urlOfS, {
         method: 'GET'
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log('response object:', responseJson)
            return responseJson;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}


let happy_songs = await get_happy_songs();
console.log(happy_songs)
```

Comment: It gives me the error : await is only allowed with async functions

Comment: use the async in function like used in this "async function get_happy_songs()"